# Access to Unity3D-created application window's code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

is there anyway for me to access to the code that created the Unity application window?
Example, in WPF you are able to set the window's resize mode, is topmost, window start up state etc. The MainWindow.cs inherits from the Window class in System.Window namespace allows  you to set all these stuffs.
I am trying to find the similar class which allows me to do the same thing in Unity3D.

In WPF

[image: The MainWindow.cs in WPF (I'm trying to access to similar thing in Unity3D]

Unity3D created application Window

[image: The Unity3D created application window]

Comment: Yes I did, I am not trying to resize. U am trying to modify the window entirety. Like I mentioned in my example, setting the resize mode , Window startup position and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late follow up, but yes this is also possible. To obtain this functionality you will want to use the user32.dll. Keep in mind this is windows based.

As this will only be nececary in windows standalone and possibly the unity editor it is worth while to use

```
#if UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN || UNITY_EDITOR
```

Now you want to use the window position as given in user32.dll so first of you will import this fucntion from the dll

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowPos")]
```

and bind this to a variable

```
private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hwnd, int hWndInsertAfterint x, int Y, int cx, int cy, int wFlags);
```

You also want to find the window, which can be done in a similar way. But don't forget to change the current "WindowTitle" to your actual window title.

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow")]
 public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(System.String className, System.String windowName);
```

Now all thats left is a function to call, so you can actually set the position of the window. Which would something like the following

```
public static void SetPosition(int x, int y, int resX = 0, int resY = 0) 
{
 SetWindowPos(FindWindow(null, "WindowTitle"), 0, x, y, resX, resY, resX * resY == 0 ? 1 : 0);
}
```

and off course, don't forget to end your #if with

```
#endif
```

Now you can call the Setposition function in a Awake/OnEnable Like this

```
void Awake()
{
    SetPosition(0,0);
}
```

The other functionality's such as Resizing might be a bit more of a challenge, but should not be impossible. You can check out [msdn windowFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468919(v=vs.85).aspx) for more information on this

And just in case. Here is a fully functional copy of the window position. Just attach the WindowModifier component to a gameObject, change the window title to the appropriate title, and the position to which ever position you want

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class WindowModifier: MonoBehaviour 
{
    #if UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN || UNITY_EDITOR
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowPos")]
    private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hwnd, int hWndInsertAfter, int x, int Y, int cx, int cy, int wFlags);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow")]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(System.String className, System.String windowName);
    public static void SetPosition(int x, int y, int resX = 0, int resY = 0) 
    {
        SetWindowPos(FindWindow(null, "My window title"), 0, x, y, resX, resY, resX * resY == 0 ? 1 : 0);
    }
    #endif

    void Awake () 
    {
        SetPosition(0,0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is the part that I have been looking for.